# Bash: Preventing part of script from running as sudo

Tags: bash

I have a script that calls several other script and I run the script as sudo `sudo ./main_script.sh`

main_script.sh

```
#! /bin/bash
set -e

. /scritp1.sh
. /scritp2.sh
. /scritp3.sh
. /scritp4.sh
```

Is there any way to prevent one of the subscripts from running as `sudo`? (ie. scripts 1 2 and 4 run as `sudo` and script 3 run as normal)

Comment: Do the subscripts need to be run with `.` (or `source`), or can they be run in subprocesses, like normal scripts?

Comment: hi @GordonDavisson the subscripts are standalone scripts that are also sometimes run by themselves with `.`.

Answer (score 1):

This should achieve what you expected :

```
#! /bin/bash
set -e

. /scritp1.sh
. /scritp2.sh
sudo -u $SUDO_USER bash /scritp3.sh
. /scritp4.sh
```

Comment: is that the right way round? So script3 will NOT run as sudo ?

Comment: script3 will run as the original user which is $SUDO_USER.

Comment: It's probably best to check whether `$SUDO_USER` is set first (in case the main script was run some other way, like when directly logged in as root). Something like `if [ -z "$SUDO_USER" ]; then echo "Not running via sudo" >&2 ...` Also, note that this will run scritp3.sh in a subprocess (as it must, to change users), not in the main shell process like `.` would.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Testing $SUDO_USER is set is a good point, which OP should do in the first place. As all scripts are standalone, OP should not use `.` or `source`.

Comment: @Philippe can you explain why I should not use `.` please.

Comment: One obvious drawback is that variables defined script1 will be visible in the following scripts.